# How to repair MongoEngine CursorNotFound

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

In my project, the underlying Mongodb framework used is mongoengine(github_link:https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine)

```
import mongoengine as engine
config = (
   "mongodb://xxx:27017/xxx?authSource=admin"
)
engine.connect(host=config)
```

In my service, there will be a large number of queries at certain times, each query taking less than 1 secon
In my log, I found that this error occasionally occurs during queries：pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: Cursor not found (namespace: 'xx', id: xxx)
Most people online say that this is because the amount of query data is too large, and there was a timeout during the operation. But my query time is very short, which is different from this situation
I suspect it's a server issue, so I have shortened my idle link time. The new configuration is as follows

```
import mongoengine as engine
config = (
   "mongodb://xxx:27017/xxx?authSource=admin&maxIdleTimeMS=10000"
)
engine.connect(host=config)
```

But it has no effect, and the same problem will still occur. I'm not quite sure how to locate the problem now. Can someone help me

Comment: "CursorNotFound" indicates that there was a query requesting the next batch from a cursor, but the server did not have a record of that cursor.  If you are able to pare you code down to the minimum that will reproduce the error, edit the question to add that.  The question as written does not have any information about the queries.